# Why is '$event.target.checked' giving angular TypeError when i am trying to use it with mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

> When i am trying to use $event.target.checked with angular mat-checkbox its giving an error sating that -"Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined at Object.eval [as handleEvent]"
>   This is for passing multiple values for a checkbox on Angular8

```js
onChange(cls: string, isChecked: boolean) {
  const clsFormArray = < FormArray > this.myForm.controls.usercls;
  if (isChecked) {
    clsFormArray.push(new FormControl(cls));
  } else {
    let index = clsFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == cls);
    clsFormArray.removeAt(index);
  }

}
```

```html
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="onChange(data.cls, $event.target.checked)">
  {{ data.cls }}
</mat-checkbox>
```

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin"(change)="onChange(data.cls,$event.target.checked)">
{{ data.cls }}
</mat-checkbox>
    onChange(cls: string, isChecked: boolean) {
            const clsFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.usercls;
            if (isChecked) {
              clsFormArray.push(new FormControl(cls));
            } else {
              let index = clsFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == cls);
              clsFormArray.removeAt(index);
            }
            }
```

> i am expecting that the classes are pushed and added to the array so
>   that i can print it

Answer (score 0):

No need to send `target`.just send `$event.checked`
I have updated the code below.

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="onChange(data.cls, $event.checked)">
  {{ data.cls }}
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: @octogenex if it works, please up-vote and mark answer as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin"(change)="onChange($event)">
{{ data.cls }}
</mat-checkbox>

  onChange(event) {
            const clsFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.usercls;
            if (event.checked) {
              clsFormArray.push(new FormControl(event.source.value));
            } else {
              let index = clsFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == event.source.value);
              clsFormArray.removeAt(index);
            }
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Use $event.source.value i.e. Use source in place of target. If source does not work, inspect your web app in your browser and the check the object name and use that object name in place of target